# AWKing an SSH command in bash script gives bad output

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I am trying to pull information from a simple bash script that pulls some data from a java server. When the SSH variable is run in the script, I can't seem to run `awk` on it to pull out the information I need unless I write it to a local file. Here's what I am working with:

```
check=$(ssh user@somesystem.com "/usr/local/bin/check_mq.sh")
ret=$?
cat=/bin/cat
awk=/usr/bin/awk
output=$($cat $check | $awk -F= '{print $4}' | $awk '{print $1}')
echo $output
```

If I just `echo $check` in the script it comes up like this.

```
backchannel_queue messages=0 messages_ready=0 messages_unacknowledged=0
```

But, if I put `$check` in the script with the `awk` commands it gives me this output:

```
/bin/cat: backchannel_queue: No such file or directory
/bin/cat: 'messages=0': No such file or directory
/bin/cat: 'messages_ready=0': No such file or directory
/bin/cat: 'messages_unacknowledged=0': No such file or directory
```

I have been able to get this working by writing `$output` to a text file on the system with:

```
 check_output="/home/user/Documents/scratch/check_output.txt"
 echo $check > $check_output
 output=$($cat $check_output | $awk -F= '{print $4}' | $awk '{print $1}')
 echo $output
```

I am thinking there has to be something I am doing wrong here and I shouldn't need to write `$output` to a file. Or, is that the only option here? Once I have that number in a variable I plan to use some `IF` statements to see if it's greater than `x`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to `cat` a list of files, that list actually being the thing you want to it operate on, not files. You want to use `echo` instead of `cat` to do that.

Comment: Yup -- this worked. I swear I tried `echo` in there instead but maybe I didn't write or something before testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the paths to the commands you're using in variables, it's totally unnecessary.  If you are using tools under non-standard paths (which you don't do), modify `$PATH` instead.

You are using `cat $check`. Two things to note about this:

1. `$check` will undergo field splitting on whitespace, turning it into a number of words.  These will then undergo filename globbing if they contain filename globbing characters.
2. The resulting words will be given to `cat`, which expects them to be filenames.  This is where your error comes from.

Instead, just pipe the `ssh` to `awk` directly:

```
ssh user@somesystem.com "/usr/local/bin/check_mq.sh" |
awk -F '=' '{ print $NF }'
```

This assumes you want to output the number after the last `=` on the line.

If you want to test whether this number is greater than some variable `$x`:

```
ssh user@somesystem.com "/usr/local/bin/check_mq.sh" |
awk -F '=' -v x="$x" '$NF > x { printf("%d is more than %d\n", $NF, x) }'
```

Comment: Looking for the output of the number behind the first = in there. It does make sense to keep it all in one line. I like your idea, I just need to work on it to make it work for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo` instead of `cat` since your `$check` is a variable. Use as below

```
check=$(ssh user@somesystem.com "/usr/local/bin/check_mq.sh")
ret=$?
cat=/bin/cat
awk=/usr/bin/awk
output=$(echo $check | $awk -F= '{print $4}' | $awk '{print $1}')
echo $output
```